# Attempting to encrypt a picture with AES using 8 bit bytes, values up to 256, when the AES standard is 128

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, byte, aes

How do I convert my byte[] so AES doesnt break the image during encryption? I am attempting to encrypt an image using AES. But the default size for AES is 128 not 256. So when I encrypt my image it goes from a byte[].length of 13,000. To a byte[].length of 21,000. Then the byte[] is decrypted and is still 21,000 in length and doesnt display.

So im attempting to adjust my images byte[] array before it gets encrypted and breaks in AES. I am returning the values from the encryption manager I made with UTF8 as well. So that's also confusing.

If the original array was 4 values of say 126, 126, 126, 125. The byte array returns from encryption manager with the same 4 values. But if you send 128, 129, 129, 129, 129. The byte[] returned is triple the length, at 12, with values in the 40/50's.

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(this byte[] information, byte[] keyPass)
{
    byte[] key = new byte[keyPass.Length + temp.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(keyPass, 0, key, 0, temp.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(temp, 0, key, keyPass.Length, temp.Length);
    // Make sure parameters are valid
    CheckParams(information, key);
    Console.WriteLine("KeyCheck");

    byte[] encrypted;
    string infoString = Encoding.Default.GetString(information);

    // Create AES object using key
    using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        aes.Key = key;

        // Create encryptor
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

        // Create streams
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {

            memoryStream.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length);

            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(infoString);
            }

            encrypted = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    // Return encrypted bytes
    return encrypted;
}


public static byte[] Decrypt(this byte[] encrypted, byte[] keyPass)
{
    byte[] key = new byte[keyPass.Length + temp.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(keyPass, 0, key, 0, temp.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(temp, 0, key, keyPass.Length, temp.Length);

    // Make sure parameters are valid
    CheckParams(encrypted, key);
    Console.WriteLine("KeyCheck");

    string decrypted;

    // Create AES object using key
    using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        aes.Key = key;

        // Create streams
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(encrypted))
        {
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            memoryStream.Read(iv, 0, iv.Length);

            // Create decryptor
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, iv);

            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
            {
                decrypted = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

    // Return decrypted bytes
    byte[] decryptedbytes =  Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(decrypted);
    return decryptedbytes;
}
```

I want to be able to encrypt and then decrypt an image in AES. If I try to set aes.KeySize and aes.BlockSize. It breaks the app.

Comment: Are you confusing bits and bytes? AES can encrypt 16-byte at a time i.e. 128-bits.

Comment: Yeah I might be, but the byte[] I get from my image is possible to be 256-bits for each byte. So when it gets returned it's in 128-bits. In a longer array and the image doesn't display anymore.

Comment: You convert `byte[] information` to a string and then encrypt it - that's not appropriate for binary data.  Lose the StreamWriter & write the byte array via cryptoStream.Write().  Modify the decrypt code so it operates on buffers as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public byte[] SplitBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        var mask = 0b10000000; // 128
        var splitBytes = new byte[bytes.Length * 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((bytes[i] & mask) == mask)
            {
                splitBytes[i * 2] = (byte)(bytes[i] & ~mask);
                splitBytes[i * 2 + 1] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                splitBytes[i * 2] = bytes[i];
            }
        }

        return splitBytes;
    }

    public byte[] CombineBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        var mask = 0b10000000; // 128
        var combinedBytes = new byte[bytes.Length / 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i += 2)
        {
            if (bytes[i + 1] == 1)
            {
                combinedBytes[i / 2] = (byte)(bytes[i] | mask);
            }
            else
            {
                combinedBytes[i / 2] = bytes[i];
            }
        }

        return combinedBytes;
    }
```

The solution I came up with is splitting the bytes into 128 byte values from the previous 256 byte values. Using bit operators, AND and NOT. This lets the data go through the encryption process and then be recombined after decryption.